# OrientDB not able to create multiple edges between same nodes

Tags: orientdb

I want to create multiple relationships between node A and node B using a single edge, but the relationship to contain different properties.

Edge:

> EPartner (description, relationdate, type, weight)

What I have tried:

`CREATE EDGE EPartner FROM #rid TO #rid CONTENT 'something'`

The above line is working when I create the first relationship, but when I try to add a new relation between same source and same target, the previous record is replaced with the new one.

I'm expecting to have multiple records on the same edge, with same target and source, just with different properties.
Is this possible ? Please give me some hints about what to try out.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to verify your case. Unfortunately, without declaring constrains on the edge, everything works as expected.
This is a log of my experiment (active-orient console)

```
2.6.3 :001 > V.create_class :test
 => Test 
2.6.3 :002 > E.create_class :test_edge
 => TEST_EDGE 
2.6.3 :003 > t =  Test.create name: :test
16.08.(03:46:15) INFO->CREATE VERTEX test set name = ':test:'

2.6.3 :004 > t1 =  Test.create name: :test2
16.08.(03:46:28) INFO->CREATE VERTEX test set name = ':test2:'

2.6.3 :005 > t.assign vertex: t1, via: TEST_EDGE, attributes: { edge_count: 'first' }
16.08.(03:46:42) INFO->CREATE EDGE test_edge from #29:0 to #30:0 content {"edge_count":"first"}

2.6.3 :006 > t.assign vertex: t1, via: TEST_EDGE, attributes: { edge_count: 'second' }
16.08.(03:46:48) INFO->CREATE EDGE test_edge from #29:0 to #30:0 content {"edge_count":"second"}

2.6.3 :007 > t.reload!
2.6.3 :008 > t.out.to_human
 => ["<TEST_EDGE[#35:0] :.: 29:0->{ edge_count: first }->30:0>",
     "<TEST_EDGE[#36:0] :.: 29:0->{ edge_count: second }->30:0>"]
```

Provided two edges between the vertices.